# Winforms Datagridview MultiSelect option not working as expected

Tags: winforms, datagridview

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.multiselect?view=netcore-3.1#:%7E:text=When%20the%20MultiSelect%20property%20is,clicking%20the%20elements%20to%20select.), MultiSelect option allows user to select multiple rows with Ctrl or Shift  modifier, but I can select multiple rows with left mouse button only without pressing any control modifier. Is it possible to stop multiple selection without pressing Shift or Ctrl modifiers?

I'm using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can disable the selection via `Mouse Event`.

Here is the workaround you can refer to.

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Selected = true;
}

private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.MouseMove += dataGridView1_MouseMove;
}

private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift)
    {
        dataGridView1.MouseMove -= dataGridView1_MouseMove;
    }
}
```

The test result,

[image]